# Ionic2 create PHP to get data for show in page

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to know how to create PHP to get data for show home.html

> and I get `Error data is not defined

I don't know this correct? please check this. I have not idea to create PHP, I want to set $path to keep my URL.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list inset>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="data.username" type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div padding>
        <button ion-button block (click)="getRepos()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let repo of foundRepos" >
        <ion-card-header>
            {{ repo.data.name }}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            {{ repo.data.description }}
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public foundRepos;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.data = {};   >>>>>>>data is not defined
        data.username = ''; >>>>>data is not defined
        this.http = http;
    }

   getRepos() {
        var link = 'http://localhost/github.php';
        var data = JSON.stringify({username: this.data.username}); <<<<this.data.username (data is not defined)

        this.http.get(link, data) <<<<data is not defined
        .subscribe(data => {
         this.foundRepos = data.json();
       },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('getRepos completed')
    );
  }

}
```

github.php

```
<?php


    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $username = $request->username;

        if ($username != "") {
            $path = "https://api.github.com/users/".$username."/repos";
            echo $path ;
        }
        else {
            echo "Empty username parameter!";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Ivaro18 help me please .

Comment: I can't see it when you mention me in a comment where I haven't posted, just stumbled upon this haha. I have no experience with `php`, are you still having issues with your typescript code? (Btw don't you have a `property 'data' does not exist on type 'HomePage'` ?) Oh nevermind, just looked at the answer below

Comment: @Ivaro18 I have several questions to ask you. Some way I can contact you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I see.

In your php you're retrieving a value called `$postdata`. So I assume you want to send the username from your ionic 2 application to your php file.

2 options, you should try them both because I do not understand php so I'm not sure what the right solution is.

But I do know what the problem is.  You're making an `http.get()` call, and you're passing 2 arguments in this. `link` and `data`. The GET method is for getting data from your link, not giving it. The `http.get` takes 2 parameters, the `url`, in your case named `link`, and an `HttpHeaders` object, so **not** data.

**Solution** with parameter in http.get

So, as mentioned above, `http.get()` can't send your `data`. Unless you add it as a parameter in your URL. Then your typescript would look like this (note: backticks instead of ' ', makes string concatination easier):

```
var link = `http://localhost/github.php?username=${this.data.username}`;
this.http.get(link).subscribe(data) { .... }
```

And in php replace

```
$username = $response->username
```

with

```
$username = $_GET['username']
```

So final typscript looks like this (since php get request returned 403, Github probably disallowed it)

```
getRepos() { 
  var link = `localhost/…${this.data.username}`; 

  this.http.get(link) 
    .subscribe(data => { 
      let repoUrl = data.text(); 

      this.http.get(repoUrl).subscribe(githubResponse => { 
        this.foundRepos = githubResponse.json(); 
      }); 
  }, 
  err => console.error(err), 
  () => console.log('getRepos completed') 
  ); 
}
```

If anyone is seeking detailed explanation to why we came to this answer, pleek look in the chat below

Comment: still error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: what code causes this error? Might be an xml response

Comment: Do you have a time? Please teamviewer with me? T____T

Comment: I'm at work currently, not the best place for teamviewer hahah

Comment: But if you create (inside your subscribe) a `console.log("hi "+ data);` does something get printed?

Comment: do this? `var link = `http://localhost/github.php?username=${this.data.username}`;
        this.http.get(link)
          .subscribe(

                  data => {
                      this.foundRepos = data.json();
                      console.log("hi "+ data);
                  },
                  err => console.error(err),
                  () => console.log('getRepos completed')
              );`               still error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Aaaah you're using the first option. Ok, did you remove the `json_decode` from your php file? And place the `console.log` **before** you call `data.json()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133973/discussion-between-ivaro18-and-fongfuse).

Comment: I  remove the json_decode from php And place the console.log before you call data.json() But it still error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Hi Ivar , I have a new question! haha http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133973/discussion-between-ivaro18-and-fongfuse

Comment: I found new problem about ionic ,pls chat room

Comment: Hey ,Are you still here? If you see this post, please chat room

Comment: Hi, Ivar can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002969/how-to-change-name-in-json-for-show-in-page

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared data variable in the class.

```
export class HomePage {
  public foundRepos;
  public data;//here
  constructor(public http: Http){
    this.data = {};
    this.data.username = '';//to refer to data in any function always use 'this'
  }
//other functions
```

Comment: Thanks, But still error `data.username = '';` and `this.http.get(link, data)`

Comment: and myphp is  true?

Comment: in typescript always use `this` to refer to class members. otherwise typescript compiler will throw error

Comment: as for php, it is not really sending json data.. just string

Comment: ohhh, what should I do? please help me T^T I want to get data in url in myphp

Comment: maybe something like `echo json_encode("msg"=>"Empty username parameter!")`

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong,I just edited github.php please check for me again. Sorry to bother you